# Cast from time_point + duration to duration fails on clang

Tags: c++, c++11, time, clang, c++-chrono

This code compiles on gcc-4.8 and fails on clang-3.3?
And how to make this code compilable on clang? =\

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void sleep_until_wow(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& time)
{
    std::cout << "zzz...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(time);
    std::cout << "wake up!\n";
} 

template <typename Rep, typename Period>
void sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& duration)
{
    sleep_until_wow(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + duration);
}

template <typename Clock, typename Duration>
void sleep_until(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, Duration>& time)
{
    sleep_until_wow(time);
}


int main() {
    sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(500000));
    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
% clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ time_point.cpp 
time_point.cpp:17:5: error: no matching function for call to 'sleep_until_wow'
    sleep_until_wow(std::chrono::system_clock::now() + ns);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
time_point.cpp:28:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'sleep_for<long long, std::__1::ratio<1, 1000000000> >' requested here
    sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(500000));
    ^
time_point.cpp:5:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'time_point<[...], typename common_type<class duration<long long, class ratio<1, 1000000> >, duration<long long, class ratio<1, 1000000000> >
      >::type>' to 'const time_point<[...], (default) typename _Clock::duration>' for 1st argument
void sleep_until_wow(const std::chrono::system_clock::time_point& time)
     ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: If you find it necessary to remove vowels from vulgar phrases or words it's a good indication it **does not belong** in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, i'm got it.

In gcc stl system_clock duration is nanoseconds, but in clang it is microseconds.

Comment: You're welcome for making it a compile-time error. :-)